# CSS Styling not applying to all Posts in Rails app

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails app with 10 blog posts. A post.scss stylesheet that styles each of the posts(show page). For some reason, my styling only applies to 8 out 10 posts when viewing each in the browsers. This is very odd and has never happened to me before. Can anyone explain what the cause might be?

Comment: Can you post some code? How does it look when you inspect the view?

Comment: @jdgray in inspect view I can see all the Ids and Classes under Elements. However on the Styles side..none of the Ids and Classes seem to be there. Seems like the post.scss stylesheet not included somehow. The funny thing is that I have a partial within this page( comments) and the styling for this partial seems to work fine(comment.scss)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing rake assets:precompile .It will load your css and javascript in public folder and then it will load for you.